# Strange behaviour when update a 2D list in Python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am a fresher using Python3.

I don't quite understand this:

```
a = [[0]*4]*1
b = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

if I do:

```
a[0][0] = b[0][0]
```

Instead of only updating `a[0][0]` with `1`:
`a=[[1],[0],[0],[0]]`

the whole list became:

```
a=[[1],[1],[1],[1]]
```

Can anyone advise how I can initiate a proper MxN matrix without getting this error?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't reproduce your code, you must've done `a = [[0]] * 4`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. I was using a = [[0] * 4] * 1 to initiate a 4x1 list. Can you please advise how I can initiate an MxN list without getting this strange behaviour?

Comment: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178)

Answer (score 1):

Upon reconstruction, with the code:

```py
a = [[0],[0],[0],[0]]
b = [[1,2],[3,4]]

a[0][0] = b[0][0]

print(a)
```

The output was the expected: `[[1], [0], [0], [0]]`

Try copying/pasting this code into your IDE and seeing the output, if you still get the `a=[[1],[1],[1],[1]]`, then it could be a problem with your python environment or something different entirely. Unless I've missed something.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! I initiated `a` with [0]*4 so that I got the error. sorry for not making it clear in the question. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Do you still get an error? Because otherwise just initiate ```a``` with my code above.